# Why does R sweep function use 1 for column and 2 for row?

Tags: r

I love this function, but it confused the hell out of me at first because I've become so used to 1 being row and 2 being column in other R packages, yet sweep uses the inverse.

Why?

Comment: I don't think anyone outside R Core can answer that. It's opinion based too, a dev can decide what gets to be 1 and what gets to be 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try thinking of the arguments of `sweep` in a very verbose way:

`sweep( mydata, margin, stats = stats_to_combine_with_each_element_along_the_margin )`

I think this makes it clearer that `stats` must be the same length as `dim( mydata )[ margin ]`, and that the elements of `stats` will be subtracted (or applied using another function) from all the elements along the margin chosen by `margin`.

Like this, when `margin` is `1`, it's (hopefully) intuitive to see that each element of `stats` will be subtracted from each element along the *rows* of `mydata`.

You could also picture it as a loop (which gives identical output):

```
mydata = matrix(rep(1:12,each=8),nrow=8,ncol=12)

# create a stat for each row:
stats_for_each_row = 1:8

# sweep with margin=1, so combining each element of stat with elements of each row:
s = sweep( mydata, 1, stats_for_each_row )

# loop over each row, changing mydata
for(row in seq_len(nrow(mydata))) { mydata[row,] = mydata[row,]-stats_for_each_row[row] }

identical( s, mydata )
# TRUE
```