# STATS is longer than the extent of ‘dim(x)[MARGIN]’ fix in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I want to multiply 2 matrices with the sweep function and it gives me the warning:

```
STATS is longer than the extent of ‘dim(x)[MARGIN]’
```

and with it the wrong result. How to fix this? The "correct/wished" output should be

[image: expected output]

```r
U <- matrix(c(4,2,4,2,5,2,6,1,3), nrow = 3, ncol = 3, byrow=TRUE)
g <- matrix(c(23,37,20), nrow = 3, ncol = 1, byrow = TRUE)

BU <- sweep(U, 2, g^-1, `*`)
C  <- sweep(t(V), 2, g^-1, `*`)

#until here evrything works fine
#the line below then gives me the warning with a wrong output
AU <- sweep(BU, 2, C^-1, `*`)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I've suggested an edit to the question that formats code into [code blocks]; it helps when questions have code formatted as code (etc), see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189. Can you [edit] your question and add your expected output? Please, a literal `matrix` is preferred, as it isn't clear to me if you're looking for simple matrix multiplication or something else.

Comment: An insightful post about `sweep` https://stackoverflow.com/a/61772932/10276092

Comment: I am not quite sure, but I think I am looking for a simple matrix multiplication, and thanks for formatting it :)

Comment: Should fourth line of code refer to `t(U)`?  The matrix multiplication function is `%*%`.